# Haystack filtering on a field returns a null set on heroku, though there's data (aka caching foreign key relation info in the index)

Tags: django, heroku, django-haystack

I have effectively a cached foreign key field in one of my indexes, called thingy_ids, which is just a comma separated list of ids with thingy_id_ in front of them. I want to use this like this:

```
>>> sqs.filter(thingy_ids="thingy_id_133932,")
```

To get results that have that thingy attached to them.

This works on my local machine, but not on heroku. On heroku, here are the baffling results:

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet()

>>> sqs[0].thingy_ids
u'thingy_id_133932,thingy_id_133923,'

>>> sqs.filter(thingy_ids="thingy_id_133932")
[]
```

In fact, no filter on thingy_ids seems to work:

```
>>> sqs.filter(thingy_ids="1")
[]
>>> sqs.filter(thingy_ids="thingy_id")
[]
```

**Edit:**
Ah hah! Adding a space between the comma separated list seems to fix the problem.

I leave this question open because there's probably a better way to cache this foreign key relation in the index and search for it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding spaces between the commas fixed this problem, though I'm still unsure why.